# To check whether AWS instance is up after reboot using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to check if an AWS instance has finally come up in python either using boto3 or otherwise. The running state doesnt differentiate between rebooting and finally up phase.

Comment: What is your definition of "up"?

Comment: Up as in all the processes have started which are supposed to ( If I reboot through putty, finally up would mean allowing me to login again)

Comment: So you mean port 22 is open?

Comment: Yes. If there is some API available in boto3 which can tell me about instance directly, thats even better

Comment: You can use socket for this part instead of boto

Comment: describe_instances ALREADY show the states required. Don't reinvent the wheel. If it is rebooting, it will not show "running".  You can try it yourself, since rebooting unlike Stop+Start, which will not cost your an instance hour.

Comment: It stays on running while I am unable to login(during reboot). So if I send some commands checking that state is running, it still wont run.
@ydaetscoR: Will try it out.

Comment: This is a good question, clear and concise. However, I think you should explain a little bit more about your main goal as you might not being considering other approaches to you're overall project. Could you tell us a bit more about your goals? What other part of the system are waiting for your instance to be 100% 'up'?

Comment: There are a bunch of instances which need to be rebooted after the VMs get created. I need to fire some command once all these are up. Now, I can't fire these commands unless all are up so I need a way to test that all the VMs are up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to check that a remote port is open you could use the built-in [`socket`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) package.

Here's a quick modification of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19196218/2291321) of waiting for a remote port to open:

```
import socket
import time

def wait_for_socket(host, port, retries, retry_delay=30):
    retry_count = 0
    while retry_count <= retries:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = sock.connect_ex((host, port))
        sock.close()
        if result == 0:
            print "Port is open"
            break
        else:
            print "Port is not open, retrying..."
            time.sleep(retry_delay)
```

Comment: I just realized, not all the nodes have a public ip. What can I do in that case? I wish to give public ip to only one of the nodes which will have internal access to other nodes

Comment: Perhaps putting this script into AWS Lambda, which interact with VPC subnet.

Answer (score 3):

All the info is available inside boto3 documentation
http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html

This will show all the information of the instances.

```
import boto3
reservations = boto3.client("ec2").describe_instances()["Reservations"]
for reservation in reservations:
  for each in reservation["Instances"]:
    print " instance-id{} :  {}".format(each["InstanceId"], each["State"]["Name"])

# or use describe_instance_status, much simpler query
instances = boto3.client("ec2").describe_instance_status()
for each in instances["InstanceStatuses"]: 
  print " instance-id{} :  {}".format(each["InstanceId"], each["InstanceState"]["Name"])
```

From the documentation :

```
State (dict) --

The current state of the instance.

Code (integer) --

The low byte represents the state. The high byte is an opaque internal value and should be ignored.

0 : pending
16 : running
32 : shutting-down
48 : terminated
64 : stopping
80 : stopped
Name (string) --

The current state of the instance.
```

In fact, there is no code state show "rebooting" inside the documentation. I can't really test it out on my own EC2 instances , because after I do reboot, it seems the instances reboot so fast that AWS console doesn't have a chance to show a "Rebooting" state.

Nevertheless, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html

> The following are examples of problems that can cause instance status
>   checks to fail:
>
> Failed system status checks
>
> Incorrect networking or startup configuration
>
> Exhausted memory
>
> Corrupted file system
>
> Incompatible kernel

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [`InstanceStatusOk`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceStatusOk) [waiter](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/clients.html#waiters) in boto3 or whatever [waiter](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#waiters) is approprate.

```
import boto3

instance_id = '0-12345abcde'

client = boto3.client('ec2')
client.reboot_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])

waiter = client.get_waiter('instance_status_ok')
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[instance_id])

print("The instance now has a status of 'ok'!")
```